# Action for a period of time Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i have a problem with my script in unity 3D.
I'm trying to make a collectable system that when I collect the item, The game turns itself on slowmotion, but only for 3 seconds then it becomes normal again. I could make it when I collect the first item, but when I collect the second one It doesn't returns to normal speed.
After I collect the second item, my Time.fixedTime gets stucked on 4 seconds... It doesn't not update anymore.

```
using UnityEngine;


public class CollectableDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gb;
    public float startTime;
    private float realTime;
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        realTime = Time.fixedTime; // Stores game's time
        if(realTime - startTime >= 3){ // If has passed 3 seconds after hitting the trigger, if returns to normal speed
            PlayerMov.velocityObject = 50f;
        }
        Debug.Log(realTime);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter() {
        startTime = Time.fixedTime; // It stores time when player hit trigger
        GameObject.Destroy(gb);
        PlayerMov.velocityObject = 1f; // It turns in slowmotion
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the code. Are you sure you have the correct `gb` set on the 2nd object? Make sure you aren't Destroying the gameobject that the script is on. Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the issue but you can simply define [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) as a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and use [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) and [`WaitForFixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html)

```
bool alreadySlowDone;

private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter() 
{
    // in case you call this multiple times wait until one routine finished
    // here you can decide what you want to do .. I would block further triggers until bac to normal
    if(alreadySlowDone) yield break;

    alreadySlowDone = true;

    // still questionable why you do this here but maybe at least check it
    if(gb) GameObject.Destroy(gb);
    else Debug.LogError("Why do I try to destroy something here that doesn't exist?", this);

    PlayerMov.velocityObject = 1f; // It turns in slowmotion

    // wait for 3 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    // wait for the next fixed update
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    PlayerMov.velocityObject = 50f;

    alreadySlowDone = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the documentation that shows allows Unity to call OnTriggerEnter as a coroutine from a collision. Is this a native functionality of Unity?

Coroutines are still the best answer, but it might be cleaner to build a custom coroutine and call it from within the default monobehaviour OnTriggerEnter().

Comment: It isn't in the docs but you can! ;) Alternatively ofcourse you could call `StartCotoutine` there and start another routine

Answer (score 0):

`Time.fixedTime` is very weird to work with. Processing power ends up being an issue with how Time is returned. It could desync in a way that gives a different value everytime you Activate that Trigger. Causing your problem.

Why not either use `Time.deltaTime` (which is more stable) or have leaving the Trigger `OnExitTrigger` reset the `realTime` **Alternatively** in the `FixedUpdate()` `if` statement, have a fail safe to reset the `realTime` just in-case